# Plot with same font of journal

Tags: fonts, graphics

I am preparing some graphics for a paper using GNUPLOT and LaTeX so at the end I have text, label and legend with the standard LaTeX font. 
Now I would like to change this font in order to uniform the text in the plot with the rest of the text in the final article. I tried using mathptmx but I am not completely satisfied. 
Usually on journal websites there is no information on the font they use. Is there a way I can identify exactly the final font in order to use the same for my plot?

Comment: Most of (scientific) editors provide their own LaTeX classes for the articles to be submitted to them, and templates using these classes. Have a look at their preambles or to the `.cls` file defining the class, and you'll know what font they prefer.

Comment: @fpast You are assuming that they use TeX to typeset the final version with no font changes. I'd go instead for looking at a PDF of the journal and examining the fonts listed. Of course, they might use a commercial font for the 'real thing'.